# UK consumer law - is Burger King allowed to charge for 'no ice' in a drink?

Tags: united-kingdom, consumer-protection

My parents had visited a Burger King where, given they have small appetites, both ordered junior meals. One had asked for 'no ice' in their Coke, as it's often seen as a classic way for restaurants to increase profit margins by filling up their drinks with useless ice.

When they examined the receipt, they discovered they had appeared to have been charged 15p for 'no ice', which seems a bit bizarre because I didn't think you could be charged for something you don't actually receive. I was given the receipt to look over.

Furthermore, nowhere in the Burger King store was any notice put up of this 'additional charge' , nor did the cashier notify of this 15p surcharge for the removal of ice from a drink that is already prepaid.

This seems like a particularly dodgy scam, because Burger King are giving the false impression that 99p buys the entire drink, but add an additional 15p when they remove ice to 'add more'.

I'm wondering if this violates UK consumer law, and if so, what law would that be?

Attached is an image of the receipt with appropriate parts redacted. I've omitted the cashier's name because this seems like a general policy (as there is no signage). You'll find the 15p surcharge under Coke near the bottom where there's 15p next to it and 'no ice' under it (compared to the sprite which has no 15p next to it).

[image]

Comment: An interesting question in the hypothetical, but in this specific instance I think that the 0.15 charge is actually relating to the regular (rather than small) meal size (i.e. regular rather than small drink and fries), rather than the "no ice". The reason for the typography is to make the customer receipt match the cooking ticket and/or the store copy, for inventory purposes if nothing else. I suspect that if your parents had ordered "no tomatoes" on the whopper, there would be a "no lettuce" notation under that sandwich(note the indentation). I've never seen a "no ice" notation however.

Comment: So you say they both order Jr. meals, but the receipt says otherwise. It's not clear, but if the regular meal comes with a small soda, then it reads more naturally as an upcharge for a regular size soda because the .15 is on the same line as "regular coke".

Comment: Another possibility is that the charge is not really for the absence of ice, but for the extra soda that they're giving you in place of the ice.  Indeed, it sounds like your parent's whole purpose in asking for "no ice" was to get more soda.